# Почему не работает регулярка?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

есть строка

```
$url="http://сайт.net/?film=229262|/uploads/posts/2011-12/1324842184_poster-474953.jpg";
preg_match('/(.*?)\|(.*?)/is', $url, $ur);

$pic=$ur[2];
$url=$ur[1];
echo $url.'<br><br>'.$pic;
```

ссылку выводит, а адрес изображения нет! 
Подскажыте, что в регулярке неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а потому что так может. `.*?` - это ленивый способ. Первое выражение вынужденно забрать все до вертикальной палки, а второму это не нужно. Даже нулевое совпадение будет работать.

А вот так

```
/^([^|]*)\|(.*)$/is
```

будет делать то, что нужно.

Или так

```
/^(.*)\|(.*)$/is
```

но вообще то лучше где то так

```
explode("|", $url)
```

Comment: Последний способ самый лучший!

Comment: Спасибо! explode как то из головы вылетело!